# Facebook Ads: relations between adgroup and adcreative?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

When creating adgroup object I can only specify one adcreative, as {'creative_id':}. And from the diagram [here](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851582_407120682719169_953595283_n.png) I can also see that adgroup:adcreative is N:1 which means 1 ad should have only one creative. 
However, when retrieving attributes with an adgroup id I saw creative_ids --- [...] which looks like one ad can have multiple creatives. Isn't this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same diagram says "One Ad Creative may be used in multiple ad groups"

Each `adgroup` has a single `adcreative` active at any given time, you can change the creative for an `adgroup` but there's only one allowed at any time.

Comment: I read that, but still how do you explain that in adgroup object there's an attribute creative_ids which is an array?

Comment: The naming of the parameter shouldn't matter, I believe that's for backwards compatibility with some much older versions of the API;  each adgroup can only have a single active creative - if the documentation ever implies otherwise please file a bug report against the docs